# How to extract number in multi line cell of excel

Tags: excel

I have two cells in my excel file, each cell contains a multi line texts.
How to extract each number values in each multi line cell.

[image]

I want to compute for the average of each group coming from cell A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UDF Solution**

Use this short User Defined Function to strip out the percentage (as a double) from the line containing the group.

```
Option Explicit

Function getPCT(rng As Range, grp As String)
    Dim i As Long, pct As Double, arr As Variant

    arr = Split(rng.Value2, Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If CBool(InStr(1, arr(i), grp, vbTextCompare)) Then
            On Error GoTo nan
            getPCT = CDbl(Split(Split(arr(i), Chr(32))(1), Chr(37))(0)) / 100
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    If i > UBound(arr) Then getPCT = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
nan:
    getPCT = CVErr(xlErrNum)
End Function
```

Use as follows and format the result as a true percentage.

[image]

**Formula Solution**

In the above sample image, this native function formula could be used in E2.

```
=AVERAGE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A$1, 1, SEARCH(D2, A$1)+LEN(D2), TEXT(,)), FIND("%", REPLACE(A$1, 1, SEARCH(D2, A$1)+LEN(D2), TEXT(,))), LEN(A$1), TEXT(,))/100, REPLACE(REPLACE(B$1, 1, SEARCH(D2, B$1)+LEN(D2), TEXT(,)), FIND("%", REPLACE(B$1, 1, SEARCH(D2, B$1)+LEN(D2), TEXT(,))), LEN(B$1), TEXT(,))/100)
```